# Implementation example of spring security csrf protection

Tags: spring-security

I want to use spring csrf protection

https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection

but the document is very bad and somehow i am not able to understand anything.
If anybody is still using it can you provide me with a sample solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying something like "i am not able to understand anything" is rather vague and makes it difficult to help you. If you have a more specific question, I'm sure you will get more specific answers :) In fact, if you have specific suggestions, I'd be glad to update the documentation as well.

Did you read the section titled UPDATE that states you should read the [CSRF documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf) and not the blog?

You might also watch the [Getting Started with Spring Security 3.2 webinar replay](http://spring.io/blog/2014/01/21/webinar-replay-spring-security-3-2) which discusses CSRF protection around 29 minutes in.

Comment: I agree with the question. CSRF documentation is written in bad way. Configuration provided ihere does not work((